# No room for a new write in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, morewrites

This is one of those very large document questions where I am struggling to produce an MWE. But it relates to restriction of write streams in LuaLaTeX vs XeLaTeX. I have a complex document with extra indices, extra float types, where the dreaded write stream limitation in XeLaTex has been a major hindrance.

The morewrites package caused some difficulty so I decided to move to LuaLaTex - under the impression that there are no write stream limitations there up to 256. However to my surprise I get exactly the same error when the streams hit 17 or so.

Below is a grep for \write on a 25000 line log file after a LuaLaTex compile. I thought this was not a limitation in principle, so why am I still getting this at exactly the same N? In case it makes a difference I'm using shell-escape too.

```
 Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
 \@xs@message=\write3
 \w@pgf@writea=\write4
 \tcb@out=\write5
 \tcb@record@out=\write6
 \forest@copy@out=\write7
 Package pgfplots info on input line 82: Found new luatex: initializing lua commands instead of write18 (shell-escape)
 \@indexfile=\write8
 \js@verbatim@out=\write9
 \@outlinefile=\write10
 \tf@toc=\write11
 \tf@lof=\write12
 \tf@lot=\write13
 \tf@lotreepic=\write14
 [][]\TU/LinLibertine(5)/m/n/12 \immediate\write18{grep -vE "(linkcode55)" steelechaimkids.tex > schaimclean.tex} 
 \tf@exh=\write15
 ./subdocs/templatetikzoddssodds.tex:5269: No room for a new \write .
 []\TU/LinLibertine(0)/m/n/10.95 didn’t add code for ar-rows. this should not be prob-lem to write code for it (some-thing like []\TU/LinLibertine(5)/m/n/10.95 \draw[<->] ([xshift=...] r1c4.north east) -- ([xshift=...] r4c1.south east);) 
 ./subdocs/templateshapepar.tex:39: No room for a new \write .
 \tf@los=\write16
 \tf@tod=\write17
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:27: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:329: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:413: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:777: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:1943: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:1989: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2175: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2189: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2198: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2344: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2729: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2781: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2868: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:2991: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:3354: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:3407: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:3481: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:3687: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:4344: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:4503: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:4553: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatepgfplots.tex:4773: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatetkzgraphs.tex:64: No room for a new \write .
 ./subdocs/templatetikzcirstree.tex:1812: No room for a new \write .
```

Comment: Extract form luatex documenation: _"We don’t support \write 18 because `os.execute` can do the same. It simplifies the code and makes more write targets possible."_

Comment: which luatex version are you using?

Comment: The limit seems to be 17. That sound as if you load some old code which restricts the write streams in order to emulate \write18. It is hard to say more without a minimal example.

Comment: `\usepackage{etex}` could be the source of the problem.

Comment: note that "No room for a new..." is not actually an engine level error it is some macro checking that a value is less than what it think sis the maximum, so if you are using old code that has not been updated for luatex and it is checking some value is less than 16 then it will give that error.

Comment: @PaulGaborit you can use `\write18` with luatex if you use the shellesc package, and in any case the special status of 18 shouldn't directly affect the allocation macros.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the pointer to the `shellesc` package.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I'm going to be doing some experimenting, hopefully with MWE to pinpoint source. Bear with me for a day or two: In the meantime top two lines of log are below (showing Lua version) - but if shell-escape not allowed without a package and if that is the cause why is engine reporting "system enabled"
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2018.11.26)  28 JUL 2020 02:28
 system commands enabled

Comment: Also note from log that the \write18 shell call to a grep did actually occur before the \write17 was opened and then failed on the next \write attempt.

Comment: luatex has a `--shell-escape` option to allow access but the syntax is from Lua `os.execute(....)` it assigns no special significance to the 18th write channel. The shellesc package just overloads `\write` to detect if channel 18 is being used to support legacy or cross-engine code that uses `\write18`

Comment: Just to understand the log and point where I need to look to try to create an error producing MWE - it seems to me that the order is (a) a write 18 call (b) a successful creation of write 15 \tf@exh (c) Then a "no room error" (d) Then despite that message, successful creations of both streams 16 and 17 and (e) Then no more streams allowed after that

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn as Ulrike says it looks suspiciously as if you have two allocation systems in place one using the standard latex \newwrite which knows that lualatex has more than 16 write streams, and some older code that is using etex.sty or perhaps lower level primitive checks and stopping  at 16 so giving errors for streams past 16. But hard to say without seeing the input.

Comment: Thanks for all advice above. After a massive binary culling exercise it is clear that the culprit is the the filecontents package. After removing the package and changing all instances to \begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{letterbankfun.txt} with or without * as appropriate, all is good - I can get 25 \writes with no problem.

Comment: I think there is an issue of properly dealing with backwards compatibility here - LuaLatex should alert to use of the filecontents package if loaded (which was previously mostly compatible) and the use of [overwrite] actually changes what was the default. Users who simply remove the package might not notice the warning in massive log and incorrect data will be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would answer this myself to close this in case it helps others:

After an extensive search, eliminating things one by one, it turns out that the filecontents package was to blame. The functionality of the filecontents package is (sort of) subsumed within Lualatex. Removing the package resolved all "no room for new write" issues.

To maintain functionality, it is necessary to replace all calls to

```
\begin{filecontents*}{filename}
...Content...
\end{filecontents*}

with

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{filename}
...Content...
\end{filecontents*}
```

and similarly for the unstarred variant.

In my view the LuaLatex developers should have maintained backwards compatibility (a core LaTex advantage) by making overwrite the default, and also if possible producing an error in the log if an incompatible commonly used package (but with identically named macros) is loaded. Albeit I appreciate that the basis of LuaLatex is to break the mould, such breaking should only be done when absolutely necessary. Apart from the risk of inadvertent use of old data, the slightly different formulation also makes it difficult to maintain documents for both LuaLatex and other compilers. The filecontents package should probably be patched also to load the Lua version when appropriate.

Comment: The `filecontents` environment has always been part of LaTeX2e, and the changes to pick up ideas from the `filecontents` *package* had to not break usage where it had not been loaded. That meant over-writing had to stay optional. On the LuaTeX aspect, there is no difference between the different engines here: you will only see differences in behaviour if you have different LaTeX versions.

Comment: @joseph-wright - I take your point that compatibility should be with the previously inbuilt filecontents (which would not have worked outside of the preamble) and not with the package -- and it is hard to do both. But the fact is that someone transitioning to LuaTex (or using different compilers) is going to see differences in output if they think it is OK to comment/uncomment the filecontents package. They will be loading old data in one version, and refreshed data in another if they don't understand. The best option would clearly be to have filecontents package updated to allow interchange.

Comment: The package author decided simply to make it a no-op with the new kernel: not a decision of the LaTeX team.

Comment: the filecontents package  writes a warning in the log, and latex writes warnings too if it doesn't overwrite files. Did you got such warnings? Beside this: with a new latex the `filecontents` package does basically nothing (apart writing the warning), so I doubt very much that removing the package did anything decisive.